# Compiling multiple LaTeX files in Windows

Tags: latex, batch-file, pdflatex

I have a folder with many LaTeX files that all use the same custom LaTeX class.  Now I want to recompile all of these LaTeX files.  They are aranged in separate folders with the same name for the main files as the folder, e.g., `foo0001/foo0001.tex`, `foo0002/foo0002.tex`. Is there a way, using a Windows `bat` script, to compile/build all these documents?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you could just loop over them:

```
for /r %%x in (*.tex) do pdflatex "%%x"
```

If the current path is relevant (does LaTeX pick up relative resources relative to the current directory instead of relative to the source file?) then you can first enter the directory, compile, and exit the directory again:

```
for /r %%T in (*.tex) do (
  pushd "%%~dpT"
  pdflatex "%%~nxT"
  popd
)
```

Comment: Any addition to this that would make it so that relative paths in the document are read from the document's folder? Say /foo/bar.tex contains /../../resource.tex. Running this command from /foo would not go 2 dirs back from /foo/bar/ but from /foo...

Comment: I get `%%x was unexpected at this time.`

Comment: @bixiou: This is for use in a batch file. When doing this as a one-liner in the shell, use `%x` instead of `%%x`.